# Sorting works on 2016 Excel version but not 2010

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, version

I have this bit of code that sorts the data:

```
DestWs.sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A2:A" & lastrow) _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

Which works on Excel version 2016 but not 2010, is there a way for it to make it work for both versions?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Add2` with `Add`. `Add` is supòrtted in all versions of Excel. `Add2` is supported only on 2016 or higher.

Check [VBA difference in Sort with: Add2 and Add (.SortFields.Add2 VS .SortFields.Add)](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-difference-in-sort-with-add2-and-add-sortfields-add2-vs-sortfields-add.1072594/)